# How to find the work function of a metal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

For this question there is a table of metals, with their associated work function in eV.

The question was: **What is the work function of potassium in eV?**

The table given:
 `Metals  | Work function (eV)`
 `Cadmium | 4.07`
 `Caesium | 2.10`
 `Iron    | 4.50`
 `Nickel  | 5.01`
 `Zinc    | 4.30`

**What I have done so far**

I have marked the above in the periodic table and checked to see a connection , such as the differences between the positions of the metals, however to no avail, since the difference are not observed for the rest of the metals.

I know that potassium has a work function of 2.30 eV , **but how can you find this out with the given data?**

Comment: Is it maybe asking for an approximation as opposed to an exact answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pure speculation** on my part here. Looking at the *extremely limited* dataset, zinc and cadmium come under the same group (column). It’s a decent hypothesis that work function depends on the number of valence electrons so the work function of a group must be similar. And it’s also a good hypothesis that work function must decrease as one goes down a group because the valence electrons will be screened stronger down the group.

With that in mind potassium comes in the same group as caesium and is above. So we can speculate that it’s work function must be close to that of caesium but a bit higher.

[image]